# Why does the standard library have a template<>?

Tags: c++, templates

I saw code in the standard library where the template was declared but the typename was not specified.

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/libstdc++-html-USERS-4.2/cpp__type__traits_8h-source.html

```cpp
00211   template<>
00212     struct __is_integer<int>
00213     {
00214       enum { __value = 1 };
00215       typedef __true_type __type;
00216     };
```

> A name used in a template declaration or definition and that is dependent on a template-parameter is assumed not to name a type unless the applicable name lookup finds a type name or the name is qualified by the keyword typename.

source: [Where and why do I have to put the "template" and "typename" keywords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords)

If this is the following, what is the use of this code? Why did they put in a template<> that you don't use?

Comment: You might have missed L147-155.

Comment: Ah... I missed the top. Thank you. 
ps: It's about Template specialization https://www.cplusplus.com/doc/oldtutorial/templates/

Comment: This is a [template specialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_specialization) of a `template <typename T> struct __is_integer;`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Scheff, @chris.

> This is a template specialization of a `template <typename T> struct __is_integer`;

https://www.cplusplus.com/doc/oldtutorial/templates/
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_specialization

```cpp
00147   //
00148   // Integer types
00149   //
00150   template<typename _Tp>
00151     struct __is_integer
00152     {
00153       enum { __value = 0 };
00154       typedef __false_type __type;
00155     };
```